# Survey data analysis in SPSS and in Stata

Tags: spss, stata, survey

When the survey design is complex, say, a 3-stage stratified cluster sampling design, then we have to use sampling weights. When I use SPSS then I see that the sampling weight it uses is the raw weight. By default it uses Taylor's linearization method for variance approximation. If I want to use relative or normalized weights, then can I get the correct estimate of the variance?

The second question is, I have heard that Stata can use normalized weights and some other methods for variance approximation like BRR and bootstrapping method. Can SPSS use these methods? Which one is the best one?

Comment: What method is best depends on the exact details of the survey and the exact purpose of the analysis. If there were one best method, then Stata would not have given you the other (in that case, inferior) options.

Comment: in general, spss cannot do complex sample survey analysis.  [look at this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/svy_howtochoose.htm) to decide which is easiest.  if you're trying to work with a publicly-available data set, [the code might already be written for you](http://www.asdfree.com/) :)

Comment: Thank you Anthony Damico. I saw a complex samples option in SPSS 20 and thought it might work. Thanks for the links.